# Need SQL with subquery to get distinct values for VBA code

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table BAR_DATA with two fields:  LongDate, Time.  Both are long integers.  No Access Date/Time involved here.
For each distinct LongDate value there are hundreds of records, each with Time value which may be distinct or duplicate within that LongDate.

I need to create an SQL statement that will group by LongDate and give me a count of distinct Times within each LongDate.
The following SQL statement, (built by an Acess query) does NOT work (some LongDates are omitted):

#### Query A

```
SELECT DISTINCT BAR_DATA.LongDate, Count(BAR_DATA.Time) AS CountOfTime
FROM BAR_DATA
GROUP BY BAR_DATA.LongDate
HAVING (((Count(BAR_DATA.Time))<>390 And (Count(BAR_DATA.Time))<>210));
```

However, if I use Query B to reference Query DistinctDateTime, it does work:

#### Query B

```
SELECT DistinctDateTime.LongDate, Count(DistinctDateTime.Time) AS CountOfTime
FROM DistinctDateTime
GROUP BY DistinctDateTime.LongDate
HAVING (((Count(DistinctDateTime.Time))<>390 And (Count(DistinctDateTime.Time))<>210));
```

#### Query DistinctDateTime

```
SELECT DISTINCT BAR_DATA.LongDate, BAR_DATA.Time
FROM BAR_DATA;
```

My problem:
I need to get Query B and Query DistinctDateTime wrapped into a single SQL statement so I can paste it into a VBA function.  I presume there
is some subquery techniques, but I have failed at every attempt, and find no pertinent example.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: @lrb Looking at the queries, I think he wants to know how many distinct times exist for each day. If so that's pretty easily done with subqueries

Answer (score 1):

Subquery your distinct table inside and perform your aggregates outside until you get the desired result:

```
SELECT DistinctDateTime.LongDate, Count(DistinctDateTime.Time) AS CountOfTime
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT BAR_DATA.LongDate, BAR_DATA.Time
    FROM BAR_DATA
) AS DistinctDateTime
GROUP BY DistinctDateTime.LongDate
HAVING (((Count(DistinctDateTime.Time))<>390 And (Count(DistinctDateTime.Time))<>210));
```